# What would be a best practice to draw a custom TextView path in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to draw categories path like in the picture bellow, problem is item shape

[image]

what would be a best practice to achieve it?

I can think about few options like:

1. Extending TextView and changing it shape
2. Adding vector drawable background
3. Adding xml drawable background

Any ideas?

Comment: I think 1st option is best.

Comment: take a look at shape themeing with new material design library, https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape. you can create a theme and apply it to textfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are my understanding:

> 1. Extending TextView and changing it shape

This will load TextView at runtime and so will not be memory-efficient.

> 2. Adding vector drawable background

This is a good practice. But the native Vector drawable support is from API level 21. To support lower api devices you will need to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` and modify `build.gradle` file as:

```
 // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Android Studio 1.4+ will  generate pngs at build time.

> 3. Adding xml drawable background

This will support all the versions and kind of the easiest solution.

> My suggestion will be to use Vectordrawables. This will give the
>   best support with different Android versions.